How to complete a swap (order-exchange) in MedusaJs?
After your order is completed (payment is captured, order is fulfiled & shipped). You can create a swap. After creating a swap  you receive an cart associated with the swap created that you have to use to complete the checkout and mark the swap as completed. The difference_due property in swap object is crucial here which determines whether the customer will have to pay or get a refund or no action is  required to complete a swap. I created a swap and followed the checkout flow I made the cart.completed req but did not received any response, not even an error to find what is going wrong.
